# Error: Out of memory in function main

Tags: turbo-c

I get this error whenever I put more of my gotoxy and textcolor but when putting more printf this error does not appear...well this was not appearing before, it just appeared in lately after tons of codes are inputted. -thanks....appreciation for those who can help or even read my question...thanks again.

EDIT: THANKS FOR THOSE WHO HELP :P

Comment: Your question is vague. Post some code that reproduces the problem for others to see.

Comment: I understand that the tons of code inputted may be too long to post here. Nevertheless, I do think the out of memory error may be related to that code, given that the error occurs since it was introduced. Given that fact, it may be difficult to spot the cause of the error without seeing it.

Comment: Hold on, let me put my remote viewing cap on.... Ahh, there is your problem! the whassimagismo is frabarking the doohickey! fix that and you are good to go! ;-) iotw - cannot troubleshoot invisible code. define your problem more concisely or you are going to get dinged with downvotes. Welcome to SO

Answer (score 0):

Fist thoughts are that you've run out of code space or data space while compiling. Turbo-C comes from the dark ages where memory models were rife and you frequently ran out of memory.

Your code has a large number of character constants and quite a bit of code in the one compilation unit, which also points towards a compilation memory limitation.

One suggestion is to use a larger memory model. From memory, you had different memory models like 64K code+data, 64K code + 64K data, 64K code + multiple 64K data segments, multiple 64K code + multiple 64K data, and so on.

A *better* suggestion is to start using a more recent compiler.

Comment: Thanks for the idea, do you have any way to help me out about using a more recent compiler, just a high school student here....well school stuffs....prolly something that can create an .exe file so it can still be graded even w/o turbo C -thanks

Comment: As you're using Turbo-C you're probably running on Windows. If that's the case you probably want to download Microsoft's Visual C++ Express from http://www.microsoft.com/express/Windows/ which would give you a reasonably up to date compiler and a decent IDE.